# Is しようしよう here same as しよう?

Tags: grammar

> 連絡しようしようと思いながらまた一年がたった。While I was encouraging myself to get in touch, another year passed. (example sentence from 研究社 新和英大辞典 第５版)

Is しよう repeated twice for emphasis ("let's do it! let's do it!" or some such), or is it something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ～しようしようと思いながら（・・・が過ぎた・経った etc.）

「意向形+意向形+と思いつつ・思いながら・・・」は、何度も「やらなければいけない。」と思ったり、自分にやるように言い聞かせたけれど、ついつい**先延ばし(先送り・後回し)**にして、時間が経ってしまった、という意味で使います。

例:

> 「手紙を**書こう書こう**と思っているうちに、数年が経過した。」
>   「**やろうやろう**と思いつつ、なかなかできないダイエット。」
>   「宿題を**しようしよう**と思っていても、ついつい後回しに・・・。」

Answer (score 0):

> Is しよう repeated twice for emphasis

Exactly.

I found another example, やめようやめようと思っても in -> http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10146298425.